# Android - initialize image from when creating new item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

I need your help to add an image inside of any object in array.
I have my `MainActivity` that create `ArrayList` of Item objects. The Item class put to every object name and id. Now  I need your help to apply any function that add to this image that connect to the layout.

MainActivity that create new objects -

```
ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new Item("a", 0));
arrayList.add(new Item("b", 1));
arrayList.add(new Item("c", 2));
arrayList.add(new Item("d", 3));
```

Item class (In this class I need to initialize the image to the object)-

```
public class Item {

    private final String name;
    private final int id;

    public Item(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

My layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/item_height">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text_item"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: do you want to show that image from resource folder or from a url?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman from a url

Answer (score 0):

Modify your item class like that

```
        public class Item {

    private final String name,imageUrl;
    private final int id;

    public Item(String name, int id,String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.imageUrl = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
        }
    public String getImageUrl(){
       return imageUrl;
    }

}
```

Comment: But how I change the image ? how I change the default image from the layout ? Thanks !

Comment: No, In the result it need to be show in the as cardview

Comment: follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/